# pytest_postgresql example raises import error psycopg

Tags: postgresql, pytest, psycopg2, importerror

I am currently trying to get pytest_postgresql running in my enviroment.
befor I start: I can test the sql code it self with this right? not just things like your database connection would work like this?

so I copyed the Sample test out of github readme:

```
def test_example_postgres(postgresql):
    """Check main postgresql fixture."""
    cur = postgresql.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")
    postgresql.commit()
    cur.close()
```

than I tryed: `pytest`

I got:

```
================================================================================================================= ERRORS =================================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_example_postgres _________________________________________________________________________________________________

request = <SubRequest 'postgresql' for <Function test_example_postgres>>

    @pytest.fixture
    def postgresql_factory(request: FixtureRequest) -> Iterator[connection]:
        """
        Fixture factory for PostgreSQL.

        :param request: fixture request object
        :returns: postgresql client
        """
>       check_for_psycopg()

venv\lib\site-packages\pytest_postgresql\factories\client.py:56:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    def check_for_psycopg() -> None:
        """
        Function checks whether psycopg was imported.

        Raises ImportError if not.
        """
        if not psycopg:
>           raise ImportError("No module named psycopg. Please install psycopg.")
E           ImportError: No module named psycopg. Please install psycopg.

venv\lib\site-packages\pytest_postgresql\compat.py:35: ImportError
======================================================================================================== short test summary info =========================================================================================================
ERROR test_postgresql.py::test_example_postgres - ImportError: No module named psycopg. Please install psycopg.
============================================================================================================ 1 error in 0.12s ============================================================================================================
```

So I tryed: `pip install psycopg`

I got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg in c:\users\a05922\pycharmprojects\try_out_pytest_postgresql\venv\lib\site-packages (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\users\a05922\pycharmprojects\try_out_pytest_postgresql\venv\lib\site-packages (from psycopg) (2021.5)
```

So I thought if I import it python may realise that the package is already installed:

```
import psycopg


def test_example_postgres(postgresql):
    """Check main postgresql fixture."""
    cur = postgresql.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")
    postgresql.commit()
    cur.close()
```

I tried: `pytest`

I got:

```
========================================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.4, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\a05922\PycharmProjects\try_out_pytest_postgresql
plugins: postgresql-4.1.0
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                                               

================================================================================================================= ERRORS =================================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_postgresql.py ___________________________________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\a05922\PycharmProjects\try_out_pytest_postgresql\test_postgresql.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Programme\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_postgresql.py:1: in <module>
    import psycopg
venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg\__init__.py:9: in <module>
    from . import pq  # noqa: F401 import early to stabilize side effects
venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg\pq\__init__.py:114: in <module>
    import_from_libpq()
venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg\pq\__init__.py:106: in import_from_libpq
    raise ImportError(
E   ImportError: no pq wrapper available.
E   Attempts made:
E   - couldn't import psycopg 'c' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_c'
E   - couldn't import psycopg 'binary' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_binary'
E   - couldn't import psycopg 'python' implementation: libpq library not found
======================================================================================================== short test summary info =========================================================================================================
ERROR test_postgresql.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================================================================ 1 error in 0.15s ============================================================================================================
```

this is where i ran out of ideas what to try next. I tried googleing the problem but i cam up empty handed. Has anyone an idea how I can fix this?

edit:

atfter suggestion of `pip uninstall psycopg` then `pip install psycopg[binary]`

I got:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.2094]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

(venv) C:\Users\a05922\PycharmProjects\try_out_pytest_postgresql>pip install psycopg
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg in c:\users\a05922\pycharmprojects\try_out_pytest_postgresql\venv\lib\site-packages (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\users\a05922\pycharmprojects\try_out_pytest_postgresql\venv\lib\site-packages (from psycopg) (2021.5)

(venv) C:\Users\a05922\PycharmProjects\try_out_pytest_postgresql>pip install psycopg[binary]
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg[binary] in c:\users\a05922\pycharmprojects\try_out_pytest_postgresql\venv\lib\site-packages (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\users\a05922\pycharmprojects\try_out_pytest_postgresql\venv\lib\site-packages (from psycopg[binary]) (2021.5)
Collecting psycopg-binary==3.0.9
  Downloading psycopg_binary-3.0.9-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.9 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 2.9/2.9 MB 10.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: psycopg-binary
Successfully installed psycopg-binary-3.0.9
```

`pytest` got me:

```
========================================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.4, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\a05922\PycharmProjects\try_out_pytest_postgresql
plugins: postgresql-4.1.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

test_postgresql.py E                                                                                                                                                                                                                [100%]

================================================================================================================= ERRORS =================================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_example_postgres _________________________________________________________________________________________________

request = <SubRequest 'postgresql' for <Function test_example_postgres>>

    @pytest.fixture
    def postgresql_factory(request: FixtureRequest) -> Iterator[connection]:
        """
        Fixture factory for PostgreSQL.

        :param request: fixture request object
        :returns: postgresql client
        """
        check_for_psycopg()
>       proc_fixture: Union[PostgreSQLExecutor, NoopExecutor] = request.getfixturevalue(
            process_fixture_name
        )

venv\lib\site-packages\pytest_postgresql\factories\client.py:57:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
venv\lib\site-packages\pytest_postgresql\factories\process.py:104: in postgresql_proc_fixture
    pg_bindir = subprocess.check_output(
C:\Programme\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py:424: in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
C:\Programme\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py:505: in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
C:\Programme\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py:951: in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <Popen: returncode: None args: ['pg_config', '--bindir']>, args = 'pg_config --bindir', executable = None, preexec_fn = None, close_fds = False, pass_fds = (), cwd = None, env = None
startupinfo = <subprocess.STARTUPINFO object at 0x000002A882A007C0>, creationflags = 0, shell = False, p2cread = Handle(880), p2cwrite = -1, c2pread = 14, c2pwrite = Handle(748), errread = -1, errwrite = Handle(632)
unused_restore_signals = True, unused_gid = None, unused_gids = None, unused_uid = None, unused_umask = -1, unused_start_new_session = False

    def _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                       pass_fds, cwd, env,
                       startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
                       p2cread, p2cwrite,
                       c2pread, c2pwrite,
                       errread, errwrite,
                       unused_restore_signals,
                       unused_gid, unused_gids, unused_uid,
                       unused_umask,
                       unused_start_new_session):
        """Execute program (MS Windows version)"""

        assert not pass_fds, "pass_fds not supported on Windows."

        if isinstance(args, str):
            pass
        elif isinstance(args, bytes):
            if shell:
                raise TypeError('bytes args is not allowed on Windows')
            args = list2cmdline([args])
        elif isinstance(args, os.PathLike):
            if shell:
                raise TypeError('path-like args is not allowed when '
                                'shell is true')
            args = list2cmdline([args])
        else:
            args = list2cmdline(args)

        if executable is not None:
            executable = os.fsdecode(executable)

        # Process startup details
        if startupinfo is None:
            startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        else:
            # bpo-34044: Copy STARTUPINFO since it is modified above,
            # so the caller can reuse it multiple times.
            startupinfo = startupinfo.copy()

        use_std_handles = -1 not in (p2cread, c2pwrite, errwrite)
        if use_std_handles:
            startupinfo.dwFlags |= _winapi.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
            startupinfo.hStdInput = p2cread
            startupinfo.hStdOutput = c2pwrite
            startupinfo.hStdError = errwrite

        attribute_list = startupinfo.lpAttributeList
        have_handle_list = bool(attribute_list and
                                "handle_list" in attribute_list and
                                attribute_list["handle_list"])

        # If we were given an handle_list or need to create one
        if have_handle_list or (use_std_handles and close_fds):
            if attribute_list is None:
                attribute_list = startupinfo.lpAttributeList = {}
            handle_list = attribute_list["handle_list"] = \
                list(attribute_list.get("handle_list", []))

            if use_std_handles:
                handle_list += [int(p2cread), int(c2pwrite), int(errwrite)]

            handle_list[:] = self._filter_handle_list(handle_list)

            if handle_list:
                if not close_fds:
                    warnings.warn("startupinfo.lpAttributeList['handle_list'] "
                                  "overriding close_fds", RuntimeWarning)

                # When using the handle_list we always request to inherit
                # handles but the only handles that will be inherited are
                # the ones in the handle_list
                close_fds = False

        if shell:
            startupinfo.dwFlags |= _winapi.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
            startupinfo.wShowWindow = _winapi.SW_HIDE
            comspec = os.environ.get("COMSPEC", "cmd.exe")
            args = '{} /c "{}"'.format (comspec, args)

        if cwd is not None:
            cwd = os.fsdecode(cwd)

        sys.audit("subprocess.Popen", executable, args, cwd, env)

        # Start the process
        try:
>           hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                     # no special security
                                     None, None,
                                     int(not close_fds),
                                     creationflags,
                                     env,
                                     cwd,
                                     startupinfo)
E                                    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

C:\Programme\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py:1420: FileNotFoundError
======================================================================================================== short test summary info =========================================================================================================
ERROR test_postgresql.py::test_example_postgres - FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
============================================================================================================ 1 error in 0.35s ============================================================================================================
```

The German line at the end says: "The System can not finde the stated file"

I have a hard time figering this out. the argument that looks the most like a file name to me is cwd. that argument is created a few lines above from fsdecode as long as cwd already exists.

is the line:

```
self = <Popen: returncode: None args: ['pg_config', '--bindir']>, args = 'pg_config --bindir', executable = None, preexec_fn = None, close_fds = False, pass_fds = (), cwd = None, env = None
startupinfo = <subprocess.STARTUPINFO object at 0x000002A882A007C0>, creationflags = 0, shell = False, p2cread = Handle(880), p2cwrite = -1, c2pread = 14, c2pwrite = Handle(748), errread = -1, errwrite = Handle(632)
unused_restore_signals = True, unused_gid = None, unused_gids = None, unused_uid = None, unused_umask = -1, unused_start_new_session = False
```

the arguments `_execute_child` is called with? if so cwd would be None and could not be the problem. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did the original install as `pip install psycopg` you got the pure Python version. Per [Installation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/install.html) instructions *Pure Python installation* that means you need  to have the `libpq` library installed also. Not sure how you would get that on Windows. I would say the solution is to:

`pip uninstall psycopg`

then

`pip install psycopg[binary]`

This will get you the self-contained(all needed libraries) install.

Comment: Thank you this helped. Sadly a new error occurred immediately. see edit. you dont happen to known the answer to that one as well?

Comment: You need to submit the new issue as a new question. Looks to me it is a problem with ` pytest-postgresql`, though what I can't say. I would do `pip uninstall psycopg[binary]` then `pip install psycopg[binary]` as it looks like you installed over an previous install and I have had issues with that before.